# frequency passage inside AC ciruit

Tags: electric-circuits

I've been checking YouTube about AC circuit lesson and been hearing about inductor passing low frequency and capacitor passing high frequency from alternating current and what does that mean by passing low or high frequency? Is there any real application example of that?

Comment: The complex impedance of an inductor goes as $Z_L(\omega)=i\omega L$, i.e. it increases linearly with frequency. The complex impedance of a capacitor goes with $Z_C(\omega)={1 \over{i\omega C}}$, i.e. it decreases with the inverse of the frequency. An inductor is therefor a better conductor of low signal frequencies than high frequencies and it's the opposite for a capacitor. The applications in electronics are numerous. They range from smoothening power supply voltages to filtering RF signals for narrow frequency bands.